# How are cookies for a remote domain being set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Hi I need to set cookies for another domain on my website. I have found a website that is doing what I need to do but I can't work out how they are doing it. If you clear all of your cookies and go to http://www.mbna.co.uk/ then look at what cookies have been set once the page has been loaded you will see that there are cookies for many different domains being set such as quantserve.com and mcookie1.com.

How are cookies being set for these domains? I thought you could only set cookies for the domain you are on for security reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought you could only set cookies for the domain you are on for security reasons?

That's correct. The site you link to is probably embedding resources from those other sites, like images or scripts. During those requests, the external servers can set their cookies.